# Rails4 error wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error When I put the condition in rails query.

```
def index
 @patients = current_hospitaladmin.patients.all(:conditions => "discharge_status = 0")
 respond_with(@patients)
end
```

Comment: where is the error??Also show the relationship too..Also check the respond_to syntax

Comment: try this `@patients = current_hospitaladmin.patients.where(:discharge_status => 0)`

Comment: You were using Rails 2.x syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple try this

```
def index
 @patients = current_hospitaladmin.patients.where(discharge_status:  0)
 respond_with(@patients)
end
```